# Object is possibly 'undefined' when using array values with styled-components

Tags: reactjs, typescript, styled-components

I'm building a Skeleton component that accepts a prop called `circleSizes`, which is an array of numbers to set the width and height of the Skeleton.

This is the component:

```
export const SkeletonHandler: React.FC<SkeletonHandlerProps> = ({
  count = 1,
  circle = false,
  circleSizes = [50, 50],
}) => {
  return (
    <SkeletonWrapper count={count} circleSizes={circleSizes}>
      <Skeleton count={count} circle={circle} />
    </SkeletonWrapper>
  );
};
```

My types.ts:

```
export type SkeletonHandlerProps = {
  count?: number;
  circle?: boolean;
  circleSizes?: Array<number>;
};
```

I know that if I remove the `?`, the error will go away but I don't want this property to be required.

And my styled-components file:

```
export const SkeletonWrapper = styled.div<SkeletonHandlerProps>`
  width: ${(circle) => (circle ? 'fit-content' : '100%')};
  ${({ circle, circleSizes }) =>
    circle &&
    css`
      .react-loading-skeleton {
        width: ${circleSizes[0]};
        height: ${circleSizes[1]};
      }
    `}
`
```

Image error: [image]

What I have tried:

1. Putting a default value for the circleSizes array at props, e.g: `circleSizes = [50, 50]`
2. Putting a default value on types.ts, e.g: `circleSizes?: Array<number> | [50, 50];`
3. Converting circleSizes to number on the styled-components file, e.g: `width: ${Number(circleSizes[0])};`

What I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it complains because you are using the brackets operand on a variable that might be `undefined` so try adding a validity check before `circleSizes && circleSized[1]`

Comment: thanks, idk why i didnt think about this lol i guess im tired. Thanks again!